# html radio onchange event does not fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making custom radio input but it does not fire change event....?

```
$("input:radio[name=glasscationposition]").change(function() {
    alert("glasscationposition")
    var value = $(this).val();
});

$("input:radio[name=copyrightposition]").change(function() {
    alert("copyrightposition")
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4mdfts8/6/)

Comment: This works in the fiddle, the alert messages are shown when the radio is 'changed'

Comment: it does not work for "Glass Caption Position"

Comment: because of the for value, see @Ninsly answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` attributes of your labels are not correct:

```
<input type="radio" id="glasscationposition1" name="glasscationposition" value="LeftTop"  />
<label for="glasscaptionposition1" class="css-label lite-red-option">Left Top</label>
```

The `id` is `glasscationposition1` but the `for` is `glasscaptionposition1` (Note the first `p`).

This is true for all the `glasscationposition` inputs.

Fixed Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L4mdfts8/7/